# C# WPF Merge DLL and .exe to one file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, merge

I've got a problem with merging DLL and .exe into one file.

I've tried to use [this](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application) tutorial but I don't understand where should I add this code:

```
<Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' == '.dll'">
      <LogicalName>%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most (all?) C# project files (`.csproj`) there is a line near the bottom:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

The blog post was saying you should insert the new lines after that line of the project file. You will need to use a text editor to do this: that part of the project file cannot be altered using the Visual Studio UI.

Comment: Thanks. An another question - the .exe file whats need DLL should be in the project?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment.